# Euler product question

Tags: euler-product

im doing a small research and i want to know if

$$P = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times \cdots \times P_n$$

can be obtained using the euler product (since $s = 1$ on euler product gives you all prime number total equal to sum of natural numbers).

Im using a finite set of primes, which means i need to know how can i get the product of all primes until $P_n$ using sums or other method.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see why it would, or why anyone would think it would.

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithm you get $\sum \log p_n$, which is more or less one of the Chebyshev functions. Investigating this function, the Euler product enters the scene.

Anyway, these products are known as [Primorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial); and all kinds of things are known.

Comment: so theres no other way to get this "Primorials" than just doing all the multiplications?

Comment: If you want the exact value I think there is no other way. If you want asymptotics only then there are results.