# What is the Euler product?

Tags: math-history, euler-product

I have two or three questions directly related to this wikipedia article:

[wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function)

I think it is exactly about my main Q (see my other Q, on hold), and I understand it quite well (sort of), but:

What actually is "the proof of Euler product formula"?

There is, of course the obvious proof under "The case s=1", but it is also obvious what it prooves:

---

"harmonic series" =

product of all prime numbers,

divided by the

product of (all those prime numbers minus one)

---

Under way, the euler product series gets inverted (1/n) and reversed (left to right). Poor euler product!

This equation is very very interesting, but what is prooved? Can you not just factor it out?

The article starts off with:

> The Euler product formula for the Riemann zeta function...:

Why "...for the R. z. function "?

Then, the article has that animated 120-grid sieve (why 120 ?), and speaks of:

> "There is a **certain sieving property** that we can use to our advantage"

I *somehow* see what follows, but:

Can not that "property" be explained more clearly? Why that animated sieve at all?

Can not "s" be left out, at first, in the method-prooving part ? (And *afterwards* expanded ?)

Why Riemann-zeta?, why any s different than 1 ?

Euler was more than 100 years before Riemann, and also Dirichlet. I don't find much/anything what HE actually did with his product formula, basically. (I know he did tons of things -- *that* is not the problem)

Is this not something between Eratosthenes and Euler?

---

Please don't blame the article -- I have been searching a bit left and right for a long time, for this "euler product series" (I don't *define* a name, not even "p"):

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 
\frac{2}{3} \cdot 
\frac{4}{5} \cdot 
\frac{6}{7} \cdot 
\frac{10}{11} \cdot 
\frac{12}{13} \cdot
\frac{16}{17} \cdot  
\frac{\cdots}{...} \cdot  
\frac{p-1}{p} \cdot $$

Above is the *inverse* of the harmonic series.

For me, this is the basic form of the "prime product" (try to google that!). Because it looks nice and simple. This also:

$$ \prod_{n = 1} 1 - \frac {1}{p_n }$$

...should be the same. The index $n$ is for all consecutive prime numbers $p_n$.

Is it only: $$ \zeta(1)^{-1}$$

...this? (should also be the same)

---

Does the Euler product not exist apart from harmonic series and riemann zeta?

---

Well yes, euler phi totient function: another "loose end".

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229307/euler-product-question

Comment: the euler_product article itself has centrally: _as is the case for the Riemann zeta-function, where a(n)=1_

Answer (score 1):

Theorema 7 of Euler's "Series Infinitas" goes like this:

> The infinitely continued product out of these fractions
>
> $\frac {2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19}{1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot10\cdot12\cdot16\cdot18}\ \small \ {etc.}$
>
> where the numerators are all the prime numbers, but the denominators
>   are deficient by unity from the numerators,
>
> This product is the same as the sum of this series
>
> $1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{6} +
>  \small{etc.}$
>
> also infinitely.

Then he factors out the harmonic series and arrives at:

$\frac {1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot10\cdot12\cdot16\cdot18\cdot22\ etc.}
{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot19\cdot23\ etc.} \cdot x = 1 $

...which he has to turn upside down because his "Observationes" are all about Goldbach and that (harmonic) series.

---

The next theorema has s=2, but has nothing to do with Riemann, or prime numbers, directly.

More with $\pi$ (the circle one, not the prime function one)

---

So this is Euler's (algebraic) proof of reciprocity between "his" prime product and the harmonic series.

---

added:

Acutally, "then he factors out" is a big oversimplification. It looks like the "certain sieving method" is applied between the factoring out steps. And because the first step is one half, the *other* half has the same size...with the second step, the 1/3, you see that it is the *other* 2/3 that get substituted.

So Euler sieves out the denominators "one by one": first all even ones, then all with 3 as divisor, then with 5, etc.

$$x=1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{6} +
 \small{etc.}$$

becomes

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot x = \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{6}+ \frac{1}{8}+ {etc.}$$

This is all the even denominators. The *other* half is the uneven denominators. (Euler only "explains": of this halved(? lat.: demta) series reamains:)

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot x = 1 + \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{7} + {etc.}$$

(I keep the original "1" instead of 1/1 -- either way it is an additional possible confusion)

Then he repaeats factoring out with 1/3:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot x = \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{9}+ \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{21}+{etc.}$$

The *other* two thirds of that half are:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot x = 1 + \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{7}+ \frac{1}{11} + \frac{1}{13}+{etc.}$$

This is the series without the "nec per 2 nec per 3" divisible denominators.

He shows the same trick for "5" i.e. factor out 1/5 and then lists the other 4/5 (of the two thirds of the half of the series), and arrives at above formula.

---

I think this is very nice, but the subtle (?) problems with infinity *etc.* can be avoided by leaving out the harmonic series, and instead calculate the unsieved coprimes in the next primorial (2,6,30,210, etc.).